# How can we use mosquitto to send push notification to android users from web server using php?

Tags: php, android, mosquitto, phpmqtt

Can we use Mosquitto instead of https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send to send push notification to android users from web server using php ? 
if possible then please explain in detail how ?
I read many docs of mosquitto but didn't found that we can use this tech same as fcm.

Comment: Nope, you can send only in your local network. Otherwise you need to swith to AWS mosquitto server or use your mosquitto server to public

Comment: I have installed Mosquitto-PHP on our server and its pub/sub working locally with .php file. As our server is already publicly accessible, so do we need to install any mosquitto library in android app to receive message ?

Comment: Try using some extension in Chrome and subscribe to that topic

Comment: It's possible, but android background execution limits still apply